# Play video in Android webview

Tags: android, video, webview

I am trying to play a video in android webview. I did my Google researches and tried all suggested examples, but unfortunately none of them works.
Here is what I am using:

```
webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {

         @Override
         public void onShowCustomView(View view, CustomViewCallback callback) {
             super.onShowCustomView(view, callback);
             if (view instanceof FrameLayout){
                 FrameLayout frame = (FrameLayout) view;
                 if (frame.getFocusedChild() instanceof VideoView){
                     VideoView video = (VideoView) frame.getFocusedChild();
                     frame.removeView(video);
                     setContentView(video);
                     video.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                            mp.stop();
                            setContentView(R.layout.loaddata_qrurl);
                        }
                    });
                     video.setOnErrorListener(new OnErrorListener() {

                        @Override
                        public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
                            return false;
                        }
                    });
                     video.start();
                 }
             }
         }
         });
```

Any idea please?

Answer (score 0):

That's possible in android 2.3 and above. 
just call index.html page in webview. and
put your video and index.html in asset folder. 
it's work as per my experience.

1. index.html

   ```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <head>
   </head>
   <body>
   what is your name ?
       <input id="name" value="" />
       <button onClick="sayhello()">Say hello</button>

       <video width="260" height="320" controls="controls">
           <source src="swipe_tabs.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
           <object data="swipe_tabs.mp4" width="240" height="320">
               <embed src="swipe_tabs.mp4" width="240" height="320" />
           </object>
       </video> 
   </body>
   </html>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I placed video files in RAW folder and access video file in default.html file by following code:

```
video.src ="android.resource://ProjectPackageAame/raw/test";
video.type = "video/mp4";      
video.load(); 
video.play();
```

It playes video like i want. Also added following line in AndroidManifest file.

```
 android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
```

Try this